# RichTextEditor for PHP CMS

Tags: php, integration, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

What RTE / WYSIWYG are you using for your CMS please?
I am trying to decide on one to use.

I am working with PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using: http://ckeditor.com/
From the page [What is CKEditor?](http://ckeditor.com/what-is-ckeditor):

> CKEditor is a text editor to be used
>   inside web pages. It's a WYSIWYG 
>   editor, which means that the text
>   being edited on it looks as similar as
>   possible to the results users have
>   when publishing it. It brings to the
>   web common editing features found on
>   desktop editing applications like
>   Microsoft Word and OpenOffice.
>
> Because CKEditor is licensed under
>   flexible Open Source and commercial
>   licenses, you'll be able to integrate
>   and use it inside any kind of
>   application. This is the ideal editor
>   for developers, created to provide
>   easy and powerful solutions to their
>   users.

Comment: Hi, Lekensteyn and thanks for your answer. I tried using that but had trouble integrating it into my code, it messes up the layout and oddly enough takes the content that surrounds it and puts it inside the editing area...

Answer (score 2):

Check these jquery based editors:

- http://elrte.org/
- http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/

Other editors

- http://ckeditor.com
- http://www.leigeber.com/2010/02/javascript-wysiwyg-editor/

Comment: I like elrte and the one from leigeber.org, they are small and good looking, but I was wondering if there is one that incorporates an image upload feature.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with CLEditor, as andreas suggested, because it uses jQuery and is pretty lean. However, it doesn't have an image upload feature that you've requested.

A new alternative to CKEditor and TinyMCE is [Xinha](http://trac.xinha.org/). Personally I find it a little bloated too, but maybe you give it a try. It has some extensions and some PHP-integratable upload capabilities IIRC.