# Rich Text Editor suggestions for CMS build onZend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I developed a simple CMS, for managing my website in Zend Framework. Now for the contents I require a rich text editor. Is there any specialized editor, which I can use directly on Zend Framework. Found digit editor, but as I am a novice I found it pretty hard to implement.

Moreover to rich text editing, I require to upload images and attach files too.

Answer (score 1):

As @Frederik Eychenié told you, this looks like a "client side" issue. You can see a similar question for the rich text editor here: [RichTextEditor for PHP CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601814/richtexteditor-for-php-cms)

Personally, I'm using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) together with Zend Framework. Zend Framework doesn't need to know anything about the editor in the client side, it retrieves the HTML data as just another form element (and validates it, of course).

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Rich text editors are mainly *browser side*, that's why it's hard for you to find one for Zend Framework, php being *server side*.

Implementing a rich text editor generally means doing some javascript to make it work, the php side is normally the same thing as handling data coming from a usual form, although validating/filtering it's data will require more work in security terms. Have a look at [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), and this [ZendCast](http://www.zendcasts.com/htmlpurifier-integration/2011/05/) about it's integration in ZF.

For image uploading and file attachment it's quite the same problem. The editor provides an interface for navigating your uploaded files and to send new ones, but you have to code at least usual file uploading and retrieving on server side and then adapt it to comunicate well with the editor. Generally you'll find in the editor's docs information about what kind of request it sends and where, and what kind of data it need have access to.

However, there are some collaboration's [between Zend and Dojo which resulted in the Zend_Dojo component](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dojo.html), and Dojo has a [Rich text editor](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Editor.html#dijit-editor) and a [file uploader](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/form/FileUploader.html). But as i never used them i can't give you any advice about them.